# fcntl is not working as expected

Tags: c++, network-programming, c++14, fcntl

So, I am using fcntl for signalling my process when IO happens on a file. It's working on normal pipes, but when I switch to fifos or normal text file, it's not working. Here's the code:

```
void sighandler(int a){
    cout<<"Here \n";
}

int main(){
    unlink("temp.fifo");
    if(mkfifo("temp.fifo", IPC_CREAT|0666)<0){perror("Error\n");}
    int fd = open("file.txt", O_RDONLY);//open("temp.fifo", O_RDWR | O_ASYNC | O_NONBLOCK);
    int fdi[2];
    pipe(fdi);

    signal(SIGIO, sighandler);
    fcntl(fd, F_SETOWN, getpid());
    fcntl(fd, F_SETSIG, SIGIO);
    int flags = fcntl(fd, F_GETFL);
    fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, flags | O_ASYNC | O_NONBLOCK);
    //while(1){write(fd, "stuff", 6);}
    while(1){}
}
```

Comment: Your code hardly have any error handling. You should set `errno` to 0 before every call and always inspect returned values.

Comment: What are you interested in -- `temp.fifo` or `file.txt`?  Sorry if I've missed the point.

Comment: I am just testing it out.